# Has GPT-3 put web designers out of work yet?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, user-interface

https://prototypr.io/post/gpt-3-design-hype/

Has GPT-3 had any effect on the how many humans are hired to do web design yet?

Comment: No. As a rule, scientific results are over-hyped.

Comment: While I have no compelling suggestion where a question like this is useful, let me refer what's [on-topic with COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).